# Jquery trigger('click') and on(change)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, triggers

I am trying to style my input=file, so I am hiding it and using a button instead. On click function of button I have written this code

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $('input[type=file]').trigger('click'); 
});
```

But I also want to submit the form as soon as I select the file. So I wrote

```
$('input[type=file]').on('change', function() { 
    // select the form and submit
$(form).submit();
});
```

This is not working when I am using **trigger** hiding the input[type=file], But when I display the Choose file. The onChange function starts working.

I need to know input[type=file] hidden and using trigger only submit the form.

Comment: try with `$('input[type=file]').live('change', function() {`

Comment: I am using Jquery 1.7 and above so i am using ON

Comment: No, do **not** use `.live()`. It was deprecated in jQuery 1.7 and removed entirely in jQuery 1.9.

Comment: @PhilipJensBramsted `.live` has been deprecated since jQuery 1.7 and removed completely in 1.9. `.on` is the way to go: http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: @Andy Then I learned something too

Comment: @VIVEKMISHRA the change event seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/9bEHC/. I noticed you're using a variable `form` to submit. Does it have the correct element? Should be if you said it works when you show the input. You could try to only set the opacity of the input to 0.

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest a better way than triggering a `click`. Use a `label` for the `input` and apply the all the styles of button to that label.

HTML:

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="file_in" class="hidden" />
<label for="file_in" class="button">Add file</label>
```

CSS:

```
.hidden {
display: none;
}

.button {
 background: #0f0;
}
```

Jquery:

```
$('input[type=file]').on('change', function() { 
    // select the form and submit
$(form).submit();
});
// You can completely avoid the `trigger` code.
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need to have a button. You can only have the input field and hide it with opacity, and with the use of `:after` you can style your *button*. Please note that `:after` is not compatible with IE7 and older:

HTML

```
<form>
    <input type="file">
</form>
```

CSS

```
input[type="file"] {
    margin:19px;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    z-index:2;
    font-size:31px;
    clip:rect(0px, 123px, 40px, 0px);
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    filter:alpha(opacity=0);
    -moz-opacity:0;
   -khtml-opacity:0;
   opacity:0;
}
form:after {
    content:'upload file';
    font:small-caps 15px Georgia;
    letter-spacing:1px;
    border-radius:10px;
    border:1px solid #eee;
    width:100px;
    padding:10px;
    margin:20px;
    text-align:center;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    z-index:1;
    background-color:#f8f8f8;
}
form {
    color:#666;
}
form:hover:after {
    background-color:#f3f3f3!important;
    color:#c00;
}
```

JQuery

```
$('input[type=file]').on('change', function () {
    $(form).submit();
});
```

Here is the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kcKqX/